# I placed different classes in an ArrayList, I want to access the methods of my class

Tags: java, class, arraylist, methods

```
public class MyEmpire
{
    private ArrayList <Property> properties;
    private Utility [] utilities;
    private Corner [] fourCorners;

    public MyEmpire ()
    {
        this.properties = new ArrayList <Property> ();
        this.utilities = new Utility [2];
        this.fourCorners = new Corner [4];

        // just examples not all initializations are here
        properties.add(new Property("Almond Drive", 2.5));
        properties.add(new Property("Kasoy Street", 3.0));
        properties.add(new Property("Rodeo Drive", 3.5));

        fourCorners[0] = new Corner("START");
        fourCorners[1] = new Corner("Community Service");
        fourCorners[2] = new Corner("Jail");
        fourCorners[3] = new Corner("Free Parking");

        utilities[0] = new Utility("Electric");
        utilities[1] = new Utility("Water");
    }

public void defaultBoard ()
{
    board.add(fourCorners[0]);
    board.add(properties.get(0));
    board.add(properties.get(1));
}

public void Display ()
{
    defaultBoard ();

    System.out.println(board.get(0).getName ());
    // i dont know how to access the getName method of Property class. 
}
```

in the arraylist board, i placed different classes. I want to know
how do i get the name of that property for example without using the
properties.get(i).getName()

```
public class Property
{
    private String name;
    private double multiplier;

    public Property (String name, double multiplier)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.multiplier = multiplier;
    }

    public String getName ()
    {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Im trying to put different classes in one arraylist then i want to access the methods of the classes but i do not know how

Comment: I'm guessing you're making a board game (monopoly, my favorite one) I would. recommend storing the squares (Where you can. land) in a circular linked list. In addition to that it'd be a great inheritance learning experience if you're not already doing that

Comment: what is the type of `board`? I mean, we can guess it's object, but that would clearly be pre Java 1.5 style and far away from best practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Interfaces defining what functionality any members of your `board` need to implement.
In this case it looks like you want them all to at least have a method to get their name. I also expect you might want to know what happens when a player lands on a board element.

Here's a template for you to work off of (ellipses left for you to fill in):

```
public class Main {

    public interface BoardElement {
        /** The name of this BoardElement */
        public String getName();

        /** What happens when Player lands on this BoardElement */
        public void onLanding(Player player);

        ...
    }

    public class Player { ... }
    public class Property implements BoardElement { ...  }
    public class Utility implements BoardElement { ... }
    public class Corner implements BoardElement { ... }

    public static void display () {
        List<BoardElement> board = ...;
        System.out.println(board.get(0).getName());
        for(BoardElement element : board) {
            System.out.println(element.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you just missing the fact that you need to cast the object?

```
((Property) board.get(0)).getName()
```